# Wordpress - Make it so that non-admin users can't see posts with a specific custom post status

Tags: wordpress

What hooks would I use for the functions file in order to make it so that all non-admin users can't see all posts with a specific custom post_status in the wp-admin back-end. BUT it is still able to be queried and looped through the WordPress post loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **pre_get_posts** you should be able to get started (to hide posts from the admin screen). You may also want to check the post type, etc.

```
function filter_posts( $wp_query ) {

    if ( is_admin() ) {

        $user        = wp_get_current_user();
        $post_status = 'draft';

        if ( ! in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            $wp_query->set( 'post_status', $post_status );
        }
    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts', 10 );
```

To disallow users to edit posts with that specific status, you should do:

```
function restrict_post_editing(){
    global $post;
    $post_status = 'draft';

    if ( get_post_status( $post ) == $post_status ) {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( ! in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            do_action('admin_page_access_denied');
            wp_die( __('You cannot modify or delete this entry.') );
            exit;
        }   

    }
}
add_action('edit_post', 'restrict_post_editing', 10, 1);
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'restrict_post_editing', 10, 1);
add_action('before_delete_post', 'restrict_post_editing', 10, 1);
```

Comment: I'm referring to hiding the post from the admin-back panel. As in, users without proper privileges can not see or edit certain posts on the back-end if they contain my custom post_status, unless there is a better way to identify which posts should be viewable and editable by the admin vs a author

Comment: Well, that first bit of code hides posts from the admin section. If you also want to block access to the actual edit post screen itself (disallowing editing, deleting), check the second section of code (updated answer).

Comment: This actually does the opposite of what I'd like it to do, it sets wp_query to the post status I'd like and ONLY shows the post status variable, how would I make it do the opposite and instead show it's normal contents but EXCLUDE the post status

Comment: You can assign an array to $post_status in the filter_posts function so it works the other way around, something like: array('draft', 'pending').  That way $wp_query will filter any post statuses provided in the array. Cheers :)

Comment: Ah I've tried that, but what it ends up doing is making it so that no matter what tab you're on, (whether you're on all, draft, published, or trash) it always displays all the posts contained within that array. I need to find a way to get the value of whatever tab you're on, (I.E set $post_status = 'publish' when on the published tab) in order to filter it that way.

Comment: I see. You can do that getting the $_GET["post_status"] param as it is present in the URL/request (?post_status=publish)

Comment: Hmm.. Wait a minute, now I'm back at square one.. Haha! If I'm just setting the post status to the Get Post status it'll still just show my posts when in the all tabs and such. Ah! I will do a switch statement where if it's in the all tab I will specificy what post statuses it should show, and if it's not in the list that I specify, do not show it! that should do it! Thank you for your help!